# What does this ribbon on the iPhone 5s LCD shield plate do?

Tags: iphone

While opening up my iPhone 5s to replace the screen, I ripped this ribbon that was stuck to the LCD shield plate and I was wondering what it's called and what it's function is?[image: I've circled the ribbon here.]

Answer (score 1):

It's the grounding plane.  Basically it reduces electrical noise and interference. Replacing it would be ideal but, if it's a very small rip, you should be okay.  Very small being 1mm or less.  It may function with a bigger rip but I'm not sure how that will affect the performance of your device.

Answer (score 0):

I removed this when installing a new flex and so far I can't see any problem. Only thing that doesn't work is the auto brightness (there is not option at all). I don't know if this is related but maybe could be ? the sensor is in the same flex of the camera etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's a grounding ribbon, connected to Touch ID and works to ground the static from our touch.

Answer (score -1):

Ground plane...  don't remove it.

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Comment: The long answer would be that I patented some components used in iphones, and know enough to confidently say this is a ground plane connector, having dissected and built several hundred over time.   But that wouldn't be the politically correct thing to say, which is why I said it.

Comment: Doesn't make the answer any better. OP says he damaged it, so it's already 'removed'. He asked 'what's it called & what's its function?' which your answer really doesn't explain; it assumes everybody immediately understands what a ground plane is.

Comment: 1. anybody gutsy enough to open and work on a $500+ device SHOULD have the brains to understand what a ground plane is.    I understand that there are many self taught 'expert's' who haven't bothered to understand what they're doing, but I'd guess they're going to 'shoot first and ask later' (and probably are't going to benefit from reading information).   A Ground plane is part of the electronic circuit - it is essentially a grounding plate.  and it's necessary.   don't mess it up...  If you did, your antenna power is likely going to be diminished, you'll have poor reception or funky colors..

Comment: @frankankersly It's okay for people to experiment and learn.